# Why does modifying a Python list of dict in this loop, change dicts parameters after completion?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of OrderedDict, which have `id` and `content` keys. I want to insert new such OrderedDicts in the list, depending on some condition which I need to find for each original item individually - in the below example simulated with `special_indices` - and therefore I need to loop.

In my other attempts, the loop recursed endlessly - so I decided to append instead of insert, and recursion stopped, but obviously, then the entries were not in order in the list. I hoped to sort the list entries by the `id` key, but I couldn't - because while within the loop, I *do* get correct id numbers - when I print the whole list after the loop is done, the `id` keys of the appended items are changed?!

```python
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

mylist = []

mylist = [ OrderedDict([('id', 15+i), ("content", chr(i+65))]) for i in range(0,11) ]
print("\noriginal:")
pprint(mylist)

special_indices = (2, 7, 9)
i = 0
newid = mylist[0]["id"] - 1
print(len(mylist))
print("")
while i < len(mylist):
  newid += 1
  sel_entry = mylist[i]
  sel_entry["id"] = newid
  if i in special_indices:
    prepend_entry = OrderedDict([
      ('id', sel_entry['id']+0),
      ('content', 'prepend')
    ])
    sel_entry['id'] = sel_entry['id'] + 1
    newid += 1
    print("prepend entry: {}".format(prepend_entry))
    mylist.append(prepend_entry)
  i += 1

print("\nmodified:")
pprint(mylist)
```

This outputs:

```
original:
[OrderedDict([('id', 15), ('content', 'A')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 16), ('content', 'B')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 17), ('content', 'C')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 18), ('content', 'D')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 19), ('content', 'E')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 20), ('content', 'F')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 21), ('content', 'G')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 22), ('content', 'H')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 23), ('content', 'I')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('content', 'J')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 25), ('content', 'K')])]
11

prepend entry: OrderedDict([('id', 17), ('content', 'prepend')])
prepend entry: OrderedDict([('id', 23), ('content', 'prepend')])
prepend entry: OrderedDict([('id', 26), ('content', 'prepend')])

modified:
[OrderedDict([('id', 15), ('content', 'A')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 16), ('content', 'B')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 18), ('content', 'C')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 19), ('content', 'D')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 20), ('content', 'E')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 21), ('content', 'F')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 22), ('content', 'G')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('content', 'H')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 25), ('content', 'I')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 27), ('content', 'J')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 28), ('content', 'K')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 29), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 30), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 31), ('content', 'prepend')])]
```

... and instead, I was expecting to get:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 15), ('content', 'A')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 16), ('content', 'B')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 18), ('content', 'C')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 19), ('content', 'D')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 20), ('content', 'E')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 21), ('content', 'F')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 22), ('content', 'G')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('content', 'H')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 25), ('content', 'I')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 27), ('content', 'J')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 28), ('content', 'K')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 17), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 23), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 26), ('content', 'prepend')])]
```

... which would have been sortable by `id`.

So, how come the `id` of the appended OrderedDict items changed after the loop was done - even though they were correct when printed from within the loop?!

It's as if `('id', sel_entry['id'])` assigns by reference - even though sel_entry['id'] is a primitive int, and not an object; but that is why I added the +0 (in hope that an arithmetic operation would be forced, and a new value returned), and yet still, the change of appended object `id`s occurs still?

(Btw, I need this for Python 2, but can confirm the same behavior in Python 3)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer while writing the question - I should have looped only against the original length of the list:

```python
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

mylist = []

mylist = [ OrderedDict([('id', 15+i), ("content", chr(i+65))]) for i in range(0,11) ]
print("\noriginal:")
pprint(mylist)

special_indices = (2, 7, 9)
i = 0
newid = mylist[0]["id"] - 1
print(len(mylist))
print("")
orig_len_list = len(mylist)
while i < orig_len_list:
  newid += 1
  sel_entry = mylist[i]
  sel_entry["id"] = newid
  if i in special_indices:
    prepend_entry = OrderedDict([
      ('id', sel_entry['id']+0),
      ('content', 'prepend')
    ])
    sel_entry['id'] = sel_entry['id'] + 1
    newid += 1
    print("prepend entry: {}".format(prepend_entry))
    mylist.append(prepend_entry)
  i += 1

mylist.sort(key=lambda item:item['id'], reverse=False)
print("\nmodified:")
pprint(mylist)
```

This results with the expected output:

```
...
modified:
[OrderedDict([('id', 15), ('content', 'A')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 16), ('content', 'B')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 17), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 18), ('content', 'C')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 19), ('content', 'D')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 20), ('content', 'E')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 21), ('content', 'F')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 22), ('content', 'G')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 23), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('content', 'H')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 25), ('content', 'I')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 26), ('content', 'prepend')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 27), ('content', 'J')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 28), ('content', 'K')])]
```